# Focus on the frame lost

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to create a portal to add users. If I enter any different values for password and confirm password, it will show a dialog box saying that both should be same. When I exit the dialog box I want to enter the details again but I'm losing the focus on the complete frame , I'm not able to even close the frame. Please let me know what would be the problem.

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: I got the solution I forget to keep repaint() . . Thanks